# INNER JOIN four table making error on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to JOIN four tables and querying the data from it. I have try the following SQL Query to getting the data from the four tables

```
SELECT tbl_user.vFirst,tbl_user.vLast,tbl_feed.dCreatedDate,tbl_feed.tModifyDate,tbl_feed.fAddress, tbl_feed.tAddress,tbl_ratings.rate,tbl_ratings.comment,vCost
FROM tbl_feed
INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_user.iUserID = tbl_feed.iUserID
INNER JOIN tbl_ratings ON tbl_ratings.trip_id = tbl_feed.iFeedID
INNER JOIN tbl_feed.iFeedID=tbl_nearest_drivers.iFeedID;
```

But while running the above query.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '.iFeedID' at line 1

Why this JOIN doesn't works?

Comment: Table name is not mentioned after the last join clause.

Comment: And ON keyword missing too.

Comment: Thanks for the careless mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This One.

```
SELECT tbl_user.vFirst,tbl_user.vLast,tbl_feed.dCreatedDate,tbl_feed.tModifyDate,tbl_feed.fAddress, tbl_feed.tAddress,tbl_ratings.rate,tbl_ratings.comment,vCost
FROM tbl_feed
INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_user.iUserID = tbl_feed.iUserID
INNER JOIN tbl_ratings ON tbl_ratings.trip_id = tbl_feed.iFeedID
INNER JOIN tbl_feed ON tbl_feed.iFeedID=tbl_nearest_drivers.iFeedID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this query help you solve your problem. In your query last `INNER JOIN` missed the table name `tbl_nearest_drivers`.

```
     SELECT
        tbl_user.vFirst,
        tbl_user.vLast,
        tbl_feed.dCreatedDate,
        tbl_feed.tModifyDate,
        tbl_feed.fAddress,
        tbl_feed.tAddress,
        tbl_ratings.rate,
        tbl_ratings.`comment`,
        vCost
    FROM
        tbl_feed
    INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_user.iUserID = tbl_feed.iUserID
    INNER JOIN tbl_ratings ON tbl_ratings.trip_id = tbl_feed.iFeedID
    INNER JOIN tbl_nearest_drivers ON tbl_feed.iFeedID = tbl_nearest_drivers.iFeedID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to state the table name in the last join:

```
SELECT tbl_user.vFirst,tbl_user.vLast,tbl_feed.dCreatedDate,tbl_feed.tModifyDate,tbl_feed.fAddress, tbl_feed.tAddress,tbl_ratings.rate,tbl_ratings.comment,vCost
FROM tbl_feed
INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_user.iUserID = tbl_feed.iUserID
INNER JOIN tbl_ratings ON tbl_ratings.trip_id = tbl_feed.iFeedID
INNER JOIN tbl_nearest_drivers ON tbl_feed.iFeedID=tbl_nearest_drivers.iFeedID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl_user.vFirst,tbl_user.vLast,tbl_feed.dCreatedDate,tbl_feed.tModifyDate,tbl_feed.fAddress, tbl_feed.tAddress,tbl_ratings.rate,tbl_ratings.comment,vCost
FROM tbl_feed
INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_user.iUserID = tbl_feed.iUserID
INNER JOIN tbl_ratings ON tbl_ratings.trip_id = tbl_feed.iFeedID
INNER JOIN tbl_nearest_drivers ON tbl_feed.iFeedID=tbl_nearest_drivers.iFeedID;
```

I think so do you think ??